# The meaning of "brittle humor"

Tags: meaning-in-context

what is a "brittle humor" when describing a movie? Is it like a cold humor? I don't remember the name of the movie.[image] Thank you.

Comment: "brittle" humour is ***edgy, near the knuckle*** - potentially upsetting, and not for everyone. Usually because it pokes fun at traditional socioeconomic traditions, rather than because it's *sexually* "beyond the pale".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Brittle wit” or “brittle humor” is difficult to explain but Collins Dictionary [makes a stab at it](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/brittle):

> Someone who is brittle seems rather sharp and insensitive and says things which are likely to hurt other people's feelings.

> > “His father, for all his brittle wit, was also a deeply sentimental man.”

If you think of a brittle *person* (someone whose pleasant demeanor is easily cracked) and the kind of humor such a person might use, you get an idea.

And the movie was *[Manchester By The Sea](https://variety.com/2016/film/festivals/manchester-by-the-sea-review-sundance-casey-affleck-1201687256/)*

Comment: Thank you all for your detailed explanations!